# Android Null Pointer Exception Madness?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

So I have 3 Activities that need to all have access to the same custom class object (let's call it 'a') created by me when the very first Activity is created.

Because 'a' is made up of a whole bunch of non-primitives, I found it difficult to make Serializable or Parcelable. Instead I created a Service that binds to each Activity as they take the forefront, and gives the Activity 'a' in `OnBind()`.

Now 'a' has a getter that gets another object of a different custom class stored with the same object (let's call it 'b'). In all three Activities, I also need to be able to access 'b'.

If I start the first Activity, use a button to navigate to the second Activity, press the "home" button on my phone, then go back into the application by pressing its icon, then navigate to the third activity by pressing a button, I get a `null pointer exception` on 'b' but not 'a'.

However if I add a line that prints 'a's getter for 'b' with sysout in the step where I press a button to get from the second Activity to the third, then there is no null pointer exception.

Does anybody know why this is and how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: How do you think anyone is going to read this? It is basically a wall of text, no structure or anything. Please format your question properly if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Please attach a relevant fragment of your code. Also have a look at logcat, analyze the stack trace when `NullPointerException' has been thrown, if you still don't know what to do, attach it here by editing your question.

Comment: Sorry Octavian, I don't really know how SO works, this is the first time I've visited, on recommendation of a friend. Is it generally advised to post lots and lots of code? I feel like I would need at least a couple pages to properly explain the extent of this problem. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want this object `a` to always be there!

I suggest extending `application`

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
    YourObject A;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        A = new YourObject();
    }
    //add getters or setters //
}
```

Now in your Activities:

```
YourApplication app;
app = app = ((YourApplication)getApplicationContext());
```

Finally in your Mainfest: Add to `<application>`

```
android:name=".YourApplication"
```

Comment: I edited the answer to show "Finally in your Mainfest: Add to <application>" The last word wasnt showing

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may want to consider a [`singleton`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class. An example (and description) in Java is [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html), but it boils down to:

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
    private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
    protected ClassicSingleton() {
        // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }
    public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new ClassicSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now, when you want to access the singleton object, just use:

```
ClassicSingleton instance = ClassicSingleton.getInstance();
```

Sherif's solution would also work (and I was going to suggest this first, myself), but I prefer the singleton route as it's a little cleaner from an OO perspective.

Singletons have (at least) the following benefits over a global object:

- Singletons use *lazy* instantiation so they are only created when they are first accessed, not when defined. If your object is costly to instantiate or maintain, it may be better to use a singleton rather than having it around for the life of the app
- You can guarantee there will always be only one instance of a singleton - a global object can have as many instances as you have resources for

Comment: Lets say, When push button, it call the singleton from first activity and set the objects within the singleton class and go to second activity, but when push back button and change something and again push the button. It gives a null pointer exception. I guess the activity clean the memory.